# Force Download using Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried the code and it worked only for files with the format doc and pptx. If I want to download images, this code instead displays a new tab on Google.

can anyone help? Or have a code that can help download problems. I want a function that can download all types of files.

```
<a
   class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
   :href="'http://api.smartsport.site/'+props.row.url"
   target="_self"
>Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `download` attribute tells the browser that you want it to download the file, but it will not always work. Internet Explorer does not recognize it, and Chrome and Firefox will ignore it for cross-origin requests ([CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download)). Since you're linking to resources from another site there is no way to reliably make the `a` tag download, even in browsers that support the attribute.

I'm not sure if this would work differently, but to avoid directly linking to the API you could try a Blob download from the API instead. There is an [issue](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/285) on Github  that addresses how to do this. I slightly modified one of the answers to make a method you could try using.

```
download: function(url) {
    let response = await Vue.http.get("http://api.smartsport.site/" + url, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
    let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type:response.headers.get('content-type')});
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = this.name;
    link.click();
}
```

Source: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/285#issuecomment-359112845

Comment: VSCode tell me Syntax error : await is a reserved word

Comment: oh, I've overcome it. but nothing happens (can't download)

Comment: Not sure without seeing more of the code. You could check if the network call to the API is being made and if `response` is properly filled before the blob is created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `download` attribute

```
<a
   class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
   :href="'http://api.smartsport.site/'+props.row.url"
   download
>Download</a>
```

You might want to use [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) which support other features.

Comment: the result is still the same, the image is not downloaded but is open on the google page

Comment: Can you try removing `target="_self"?`

Comment: That's weird. Can you share a complete url?